# Configure Spring Boot Test to use separate sets of beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want for my Spring Boot test to use new instances for beans for each test run. Which part of the test configuration can I set it?

Comment: You want to use new instance of the beans or replace them with different implementation?

Comment: Just fresh instances for each test.

Comment: I you need a new instances for beans for each tests method and you are using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, check out @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna take a look at the @DirtiesContext annotation. Once state of the bean will be modified, new context will be provided:

There are few options to run with, namely:

> - Before current test class: when declared at the class level with class mode set to BEFORE_CLASS
> - Before each test method in current test class: when declared at the class level with class mode set to BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD
> - Before current test method: when declared at the method level with method mode set to BEFORE_METHOD
> - After current test method: when declared at the method level with method mode set to AFTER_METHOD
> - After each test method in current test class: when declared at the class level with class mode set to AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD
> - After current test class: when declared at the class level with class mode set to AFTER_CLASS

for further reading, please take a look at:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DirttiesContext like pezetem wrote.

But if you must have fresh instances of beans for test try refactor your tests and maybe code because you probably will have problems with working app.